# 408 Request timeout after 5 minutes on some servers

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, hyper, rust-axum, async-graphql

I am getting 408 Request Timeout every 5 minutes on some servers. In the trace logs, these servers have the keep_alive status as Disabled.

```
[2024-01-17T01:59:01Z TRACE hyper::proto::h1::conn] flushed({role=server}): State { reading: Body(Length(37703933)), writing: Init, keep_alive: Disabled }
[2024-01-17T01:59:01Z TRACE hyper::proto::h1::decode] decode; state=Length(37703933)
[2024-01-17T01:59:01Z TRACE hyper::proto::h1::io] received 0 bytes
[2024-01-17T01:59:01Z DEBUG hyper::proto::h1::conn] incoming body decode error: end of file before message length reached
```

I am using `axum` to configure my server on the backend as below:

```rust
let app = Router::new()
   .route("/api", get(graphiql).post(graphql_handler))
   .route("/api/", get(graphiql).post(graphql_handler))
   .layer(Extension(schema))
   .layer(CorsLayer::permissive())
   .layer(
       ServiceBuilder::new()
           .layer(HandleErrorLayer::new(|_: BoxError| async {
               info!(target: LOG_TARGET, "timeout occured");
               StatusCode::REQUEST_TIMEOUT
           }))
           .layer(TimeoutLayer::new(Duration::from_secs(3600))),
   )
   .layer(TraceLayer::new_for_http());
```

The timeout is happening when uploading a file and takes more than 5 minutes.
The upload is done using the async-graphql Upload feature.

```rust
pub struct FileUploadForm {
    pub new_file: Upload,
}
async fn upload_file<'a>(&self, ctx: &Context<'a>, form: FileUploadForm) -> Result<bool> {
    // File handling logic
}
```

The following is request header:

```
Request URL: http://domain/api/
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en
Content-Length: 38878148
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryodalzl0fqvm4RwDW
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Sec-Gpc: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

How can I configure the server to keep the connection open?

Comment: hi. did u solve the problem ?

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply, yes, the issue was because of http-proxy-middleware running on nodejs to host the static website. Few servers were running custom nodejs proxy to serve the pages and some servers where configured with nginx. Once all servers are configured with nginx the issue was resolved.